# Write and read username and password function in text file using php

Tags: php

i have problems with my login page. Im still new to php and my teacher told me to create a login page using php and you read your username and password from text file.. and if the username is correct then should go to next page and if there are no exists username it will print an output says that no username.

please help..

**These are my login.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form action="logg.php" method="POST">
        <br /> Name: <input type="text" name="uname"><br /> Password: <input
            type="password" name="password" size="15" maxlength="30" /> <br /> <input
            type="submit" name="login" value="Post!"> <br />
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**And these are my login.php**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['login'])){
$myFile = "accounts.txt";

$myFileLink = fopen($myFile, 'r');

$myFileContents = fread($myFileLink, filesize($myFile));

fclose($myFileLink);

echo $myFileContents;
?>
```

the answer only shows all the name but what my teacher asked me to do is that only read the certain names.. and i have no idea what to do.. please help

This should be like this :

[I dont know what to do..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCulc.png)

Comment: show us your accounts.txt file structure first

Comment: for one thing, you're not doing anything with the inputs other than the submit button.

Comment: I also don't see where you're comparing anything. I think you should either post the code for it, or if you don't have any for it, to Google this. There are solutions out there, you just need to go look for them. Use "compare username and password from a text file php" and you will get results.

Comment: There are my accounts.txt  Hanna,2302
Lala,ha2302

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to find the certain string (username = Bob) in your .txt

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Or you can try to use unserialize

```
// set data for example 
$store = array( 
        'username' => 'Bob', 
        'password' => 'YouShouldNotPass' 
    ); 

$fp = fopen('pass.txt','w'); 

fwrite($fp,serialize($store)); 


// Reading the data 
$passtxt = file_get_contents('pass.txt'); 
$info = unserialize($passtxt); 

echo $info['username'];
```

Or you can try json:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: what is this function for? im sorry im new to php so i dont really know how :(

Answer (score 0):

I hope it'll give you some intuition that how can you read specific username and match after login form submission.

```
$myFile = "accounts.txt";
//$string = file_get_contents($myFile); //you've to read it like this

$string = 'Hanna,2302 Lala,ha2302'; // I assume you have this data on file

$username_password = explode(' ',$string);

foreach($username_password as $u_p){

 list($username,$password) = explode(',',$u_p);  //map it to 2 different variable
 // you can add any kind of condition to match specific user after login
 echo "username = $username & password = $password <br/>";
}
```

**Edit:**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['login'])){ 
    $myFile = "accounts.txt"; 
    //$string = file_get_contents($myFile); //you've to read it like this
    $string = 'Hanna,2302 Lala,ha2302'; // I assume you have this data on file
    $username_password = explode(' ',$string); 
    foreach($username_password as $u_p){ 
        list($username,$password) = explode(',',$u_p);//map it to 2 different variable 
        // you can add any kind of condition to match specific user after login
        echo "username = $username & password = $password <br/>";
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: I still have this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Awep Tutorial 1\PHP\logg.php on line 16

Comment: i did.. <?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
$myFile = "accounts.txt";
//$string = file_get_contents($myFile); //you've to read it like this

$string = 'Hanna,2302 Lala,ha2302'; // I assume you have this data on file

$username_password = explode(' ',$string);

foreach($username_password as $u_p){

 list($username,$password) = explode(',',$u_p);  //map it to 2 different variable
 // you can add any kind of condition to match specific user after login
 echo "username = $username & password = $password <br/>";
}
?>

Comment: you missed a brace `}` at last line. See my `Edit` answer

Comment: it works! thank you.. how do you connect it to new web page? after login?